# Is it possible to update an app with Android Google Maps API V1?

Tags: android

I am having problems with updating an Android Project that is using Google Maps Api v1.
According to Google:

> Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API has been officially
>   deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. This means that from March 18th,
>   2013 you will no longer be able to request an API key for this
>   version. No new features will be added to Google Maps Android API v1.
>   However, apps using v1 will continue to work on devices. Existing and
>   new developers are encouraged to use Google Maps Android API v2.

Does it mean that in order to update the app I need to update the maps to use Google Maps API v2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue using v1 for the time being.

The warning simply says that you won't be getting any new features, and you can't request new API keys for v1.

As per your quote:

> However, **apps using v1 will continue to work on devices.**